# Installing Crossover 11.3.1 .deb Fails

Tags: installation, package-management, deb

I keep getting the same messege every time i install a deb file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 489, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sessioninstaller/core.py", line 669, in _install_package_files
    interaction, sender)
TypeError: install_package_files() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Comment: That's kind of ambiguous.  What are you trying to install?

Comment: crossover-11.3.1

Comment: from the repositories or a third party package?  And what command(s) were you using to install it?

Comment: just fyi i'm kinda a new user but basically it's a .deb package so i click it and it asks if i want to install the file. i click install and it throws up that messege

Comment: @user151675, Its better to add answers to comments, which makes the question more clear, to the question itself, so that people who might want to help you can find all useful info in the question itself, rather than going through all comments.

Comment: Are you using a 64bit version of Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

Open up the terminal.

Given that you told me this deb is in your downloads folder, type in this command: `cd Downloads`

Then, since you know the file name, do `sudo dpkg --install [filename]`

Replace `[filename]` with the filename for the deb file as it is in your Downloads folder.

That should install the .deb file, unless there are missing dependencies.

Comment: yea it says it's missing dependencies. here's the text it showed me.

Comment: dpkg: error processing ia32-crossover (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ia32-crossover

Comment: Add the error message to your question using the "edit" button, the ENTIRE error message, including the missing dependencies error.

Comment: Unpacking replacement ia32-crossover ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ia32-crossover:
 ia32-crossover depends on libc6-i386; however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 ia32-crossover depends on ia32-libs | ia32-apt-get; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.
  Package ia32-apt-get is not installed.
 ia32-crossover depends on lib32gcc1; however:
  Package lib32gcc1 is not installed.
 ia32-crossover depends on lib32nss-mdns; however:
  Package lib32nss-mdns is not installed.
 ia32-crossover depends on lib32z1; however:
  Package lib32z1 is not installed.

Comment: I said as an edit to your answer.  NOT as a comment.  [This link should allow you to edit your own post.](http://askubuntu.com/posts/284824/edit)

Comment: ia32-crossover depends on lib32asound2; however:
  Package lib32asound2 is not installed.